# How to make project documentation only to the end users?

Tags: angular, nginx

I need to place a link/icon in one of the angular component. when i click on the link it should open the documentation html index page however i am not able restrict the documentation only to the end users. I am using nginx to deploy my angular app and also to serve the project documentation.

so here is a part from my angulare component code.

```
<a href='{{documentationLink}}'>documentation</a>
```

following is my nginx configuration . the ui code is placed in the folder /usr/share/nginx/html and the html documentation is placed in the folder /usr/share/nginx/html/mep-docs.

```
 server {
        server_name primecast-vagrant;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/primecast-nginx.log main;
        index  index.html;
        location /MEP {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/mep-docs;
        index  index_MEP.htm;
       }
   }
```

so my question is how can i restrict access to the documentation only to the users who logged into the application?

Comment: see `guards` in angular-router. :D like `canactivate, candeactivate` etc.

Comment: Hi jai just want to know where do we usually place the html user documentation. do we place it in nginx or will it be part of the angular folder structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pretty much depends what you are trying to accomplish...

If you restrict the `path` in `angular-router` via `guard`, the data could still be extracted from the loaded `.js` files. You could negate this effect by using [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and lazy-load the required `.js` files.

You could also restrict the access to the `/usr/share/nginx/html/mep-docs` path via `nginx` ala:

```
location /MEP {
  auth_basic "Authentication required";
  auth_basic_user_file </path/to/htpasswd>;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/mep-docs;
  index  index_MEP.htm;
}
```

which would result in an auth-check for all subpaths of `/MEP`. You can read a guide about it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Personally I would split the two applications and restrict the documentation via `nginx`.

Hope it helps,
G

Comment: currently i am running a java backend and angular ui in the front end. the user login via username and password which are stored in cassandra. internally we are using json web tokens to access the rest java backend api. what i would like to do is if the user access the project documentation link if there is no session opened or expired the user should be redirected to the login page. will it be possible ? thank you so much

Comment: If your frontend is already behind a login and the documentation is run at the same domain, you can just access the `session-token` or `jwt` from your `local storage` or `cookies` and check it with `guard` in your angular router